# Basic Representation Theorey: Bijective Correspondence Between Representations (Dummit and Foote 18.1 #3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am working on the following question from Dummit and Foote:

Prove that the degree 1 representations of $G$ are in bijective correspondence with the degree 1 representations of $G/G'$ (where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$).

My general strategy was to note that we can think of degree one representations of $G$ as maps $\phi : G \to F^x$.  I then showed that $G'$ is included in the kernel of any such homomorphism. So we could define a new map $\phi ': G/G' \to F^x$, with $\phi = \phi ' (\pi(g))$, where $\pi$ is the natural projection.  I showed that such a $\phi '$ was well-defined.

I'm now working on the showing the bijection part.  I did not see an obvious claim that these maps were inverses somehow.  I was wondering if there was a general way to show that a map like $\phi '$ could uniquely be lifted to a map like $\phi$?

Last time I did work with lifts and homomorphisms it was in the context of exact sequences... I'm not sure if this a productive way to think about this question, or if there is an easier way?

Comment: Have you ever seen the universal property of the abelianization (that is $G/G'$)?

Comment: Ah, yes! It had totally slipped my mind! Thank you.